# Can't connect to private gitlab with ssh

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I'm trying to clone a private gitlab repository but I need first to connect with ssh. I correctly created my private and public keys and linked them with my gitlab account. But, when I use the command `ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.XXX.fr` this is why I get :

[image]

Do you maybe have a solution ?

**Update :** I tried by using Git Bash but it doesn't worked. ( I'm using Windows 11 )

Comment: "Connection timed out" usually means a network issue.

Comment: Are you sure your instance is using port 22 for git over ssh? That's the default, but your system administrators may have changed it, in which case you must add the port to your ssh config and/or remote URL.